# How do I set a HTTP response header in middleware which is not discarded when a MVC Core controller throws an exception?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, httpresponse

The following program creates a simple ASP.NET MVC Core 2.2.0 site with two routes:

- `/success` - returns the string "Success Response".
- `/failure` - throws an exception, causing a 500 to be returned

There is additionally middleware which sets a HTTP response header of `X-Added-Key`/`X-Added-Value`.  It does this using the `OnStarting` event, which, according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpresponse.onstarting?view=aspnetcore-2.2) "Adds a delegate to be invoked just before response headers will be sent to the client.".

However, what I'm seeing is that my HTTP response header is erased when MVC handles an exception for the `/failure` route; the middleware is definitely hit, but the response is missing the `X-Added-Key` HTTP response header.  I suspect this is being done [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/28157e62597bf0e043bc7e937e44c5ec81946b83/src/Middleware/Diagnostics/src/ExceptionHandler/ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.cs#L71).

How should I set a HTTP response header so that MVC does not discard it in the event of an exception?  My use case here is that we're looking to return a request ID so that API consumers can give us a reference if they would like to report a bug, so it should be returned regardless of whether the controller encountered an exception.

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ResponseHeadersSanityCheck
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build()
            .Run();
        }
    }

    public sealed class ExampleController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet, Route("success")]
        public string Success() => "Success Response";

        [HttpGet, Route("failure")]
        public string Failure() => throw new Exception("Failure Response");
    }

    public sealed class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app
                .Use(async (HttpContext context, Func<Task> next) =>
                {
                    context.Response.OnStarting(() =>
                    {
                        context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Added-Key", "X-Added-Value");
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    });
                    await next();
                })
                .UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could capture the exception between the middleware handling.

Try

```
app.Use(async (HttpContext context, Func<Task> next) =>
    {
        context.Response.OnStarting(() =>
        {
            context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Added-Key", "X-Added-Value");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        });
        try
        {
            await next();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }).UseMvc();
```

Update:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.Use(async (HttpContext context, Func<Task> next) =>
        {
            context.Response.OnStarting(() =>
            {
                context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Added-Key", "X-Added-Value");
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            });
            await next();
        }).UseMvc();            
}
```

Update:

```
app.Use(async (HttpContext context, Func<Task> next) =>
    {
        context.Response.OnStarting(() =>
        {
            context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Added-Key", "X-Added-Value");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        });
        //await next();
        try
        {
            await next();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 500;
        }
    }).UseMvc();
```

Comment: This unfortunately breaks all other aspects of the default exception handler; for instance, I see a 200 OK rather than a 500 Internal Server Error on GET /failure.

Comment: @jameswilddev What is your expected result? Try the update.

Comment: That does work, but UseDeveloperExceptionPage should not be used in production.

Comment: @jameswilddev What is your expected reponse for production?

Comment: Exactly the same as my code sample produces (500, default exception handler hit, etc.) but with the X-Added-Key header set to X-Added-Value.  Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: @jameswilddev Do you mean 500 internal server error? Check the update